# Show display values for a foreign key property in a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a model that looks kinda like this:

```
public class Notes
{
public int NoteID {get; set;}
public string Note {get; set;}
public int CustomerID {get; set;}
{
```

On the Notes Details view, I would like to be able to show Customer Name instead of CustomerID. Obviously if this were a Create or Edit view I use a dropdown list.
However I am not sure how to show the value and not the ID in a read only Details view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code First is mainly... code, not Database logic.

So, instead of having the Foreign Keys (like CustomerID) in your models (it's also possible, and sometimes needed, but not always), you'll be more confortable having a reference property

```
public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}
```

So in your view having Notes as Model, you could simply use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Customer.Name);
```

When you retrieve your Notes entity, don't forget to include the related entities / properties needed for your View / ViewModel (I let you read about lazy loading)

Comment: @Lucky Well you can have navigation properties with code first, db first or model first... So still the same.

Comment: this is my first project in mvc  @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.ParentID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ParentID) it is binded in List of records how to set the key value to be selected in the table it show all the values but don't select particular Name for that value any idea ?

Comment: same thing work for a single record var st = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var cat in coll)
            {
                st.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = cat.Name,
                    Value = cat.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = cat.ID == selected
                });

            }
            var s = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Resources.lblSelect,
                Value = "0"
            };
            st.Insert(0, s);
            ViewBag.ParentID =  st; show selected value in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.Notes.Include(n => n.Custumer);
return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
```

This code must be in your controller, in the Index method or whatever you named it.
And this is in view.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Name)
```